# Find solution using infinite descent.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem, fermat-numbers

Can someone help with a task? Need to find a solution other than $(0,0,0)  $ with infinite descent. $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$. Any help would be appreciated.

The equation is    $x^2-3y^2=2z^2$.
I tried to write it down as $x^2 ≡y^2 ≡0 \pmod 2$. Then $x^2 =a\cdot2$ and $y^2=b\cdot2$. Then $a\cdot2-3\cdot b\cdot 2=2z^2.$ And it doesn't work any further

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts along with some context.  I take it that $x,y,z$ are meant to be integers, yes?  And that by "find a solution" you mean "show that no solution other that $(0,0,0)$ exists", right?

Comment: @Iulu yes, you're completely right

Comment: Please edit you post accordingly, and include your efforts.  There is an obvious prime to reduce with respect to...what happens when you do that?

Comment: Try to find some small positive integer $(n)$ where it can be shown that all $3$ terms, $x^2, 3y^2,$ and $2z^2$ must each be a multiple of $(n)$.  Then, you can consider how this affects $x,y,$ and $z$.  If you can show that $x,y,$ and $z$ are each divisible by some positive integer $(M)$, then you can **descend** the equation to a consideration of $$\left[\frac{x}{M}\right]^2 - 3\left[\frac{y}{M}\right]^2 = 2\left[\frac{z}{M}\right]^2.$$

Comment: @Iulu, I tried to write it down as  x^2 ≡y^2 ≡0 (mod 2). Then x^2 =a*2 and y^2=b*2. Then a*2-3*b*2=2z^2. And it doesn't work any further

Comment: Please keep trying.  Also, please re-read the first sentence in the first comment of lulu: "Please edit to include your efforts along with some context."  This request signifies asking you to edit your posting, rather than providing explanatory comments.  For a more detailed explanation of the information that your posting should provide, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  Also, I suggest that you take a closer look at my first comment.

Comment: @Katli  Right...So $2$ is not a good prime to reduce with respect to.  Try another one.

Comment: Tried it with 5. Still doesn't work.

Comment: For any positive integer $k$, it is impossible for $k^2$ to be congruent to $2 \pmod{3}$.  This problem will succumb to a modulo $(3)$ argument.

Comment: I can't anymore :(( I can't even make it with (mod 3)

Comment: you can prove things $\pmod 8$  or $\pmod 9.$  The first says that, if the form is zero mod that prime power, all the variables are even; the second that all are divisible by $3.$  The descent is this:  if there are any nonzero $x,y,z$  that satisfy the desired equation, then there is  such a triple $x_0, y_0, z_0$ with $ \gcd(x_0, y_0, z_0 ) = 1.$  There are many ways to express infinite descent; this way is cleanest for quadratic forms, descend to a coprime triple

Comment: @lulu   if we have integer variables with $x^2 - 3 y^2 \equiv  2 z^2 \pmod 8,$  then $x,y,z$   must all be even. followed by:  if there is any solution with $(x,y,z)$   not all zero, then there is such a triple with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1.$  And so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Show that the equation

> $$x^2 - 3y^2 = 2z^2 \tag1 $$

> has no solution in positive integers, by using the argument of infinite descent.

First, consider what the argument of infinite descent signifies.

The set of all positive integers are bounded below, by the number $(+1)$, which is the smallest possible positive integer.

Suppose that it could be shown that (1) above has a solution in positive integers.  You could let the set $S$ denote the set of all ordered triples
$\{(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2), \cdots \}$ that represent a positive integer solution to (1) above.  Then, from this set $S$, you could **order** the elements by the size of the first component of each ordered triple.

That is, you could **construe** that the solution $(x_1, y_1, z_1) \leq $ the solution $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ if and only if $x_1 \leq x_2$.

Then, because the positive integers are bounded below, there would have to be some specific value $X$ which represents the minimum value of the first component of any of the ordered triples in the set $S$.

Suppose further, that it could be shown that for **any** element $(X,Y,Z)$  that is in the set $S$, that $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{X}{3}, \frac{Y}{3}, \frac{Z}{3}\right)~$ is **also** in the set $S$.

This would contradict the assertion that the set $S$ has a **smallest** element.  This situation would therefore be impossible, because the positive integers are bounded below by $(+1)$.

Therefore, it is sufficient to show that if $(X,Y,Z)$ is an element in the set $S$, that so is $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{X}{3}, \frac{Y}{3}, \frac{Z}{3}\right)$.

So, the problem reduces to showing that

$$(X,Y,Z) \in S \implies \left(\frac{X}{3}, \frac{Y}{3}, \frac{Z}{3}\right) \in S. \tag2 $$

To show, (2) above, first I will establish some preliminary results.  Then, I will use these preliminary results.

---

**Preliminary Results**

$\underline{\text{Lemma 1}: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+} \implies n^2 \not\equiv 2\pmod{3}}$

**Proof**
When any positive integer $n$ is divided by $3$, the remainder will have to be some element $r$ in $\{0,1,2\}$.  Therefore, Lemma 1 may be established by verifying that it holds for all three possible values for $r$.

$(3k + 0)^2 = 9k^2 + 0k + 0^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$ 
$(3k + 1)^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}.$ 
$(3k + 2)^2 = 9k^2 + 12k + 2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{3} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Lemma 2}: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, 2n \equiv 1\pmod{3} \implies n \equiv 2\pmod{3}}$

**Proof**
Use the same type of approach as was used in Lemma 1. 
$2 \times (3k + 0) = 6k \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$ 
$2 \times (3k + 1) = 6k + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$ 
$2 \times (3k + 2) = 6k + 4 \equiv 4 \pmod{3} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}.$

Only the last case, $(3k + 2)$ generated a product that was congruent to $(1) \pmod{3}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Lemma 3}: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, n \equiv 0\pmod{3} \implies n^2 \equiv 0\pmod{9}}$

**Proof**
$n \equiv 0\pmod{3}$ implies that $n$ may be expressed as $(3k)$. 
Then $n^2 = 9k^2$ which is a multiple of $(9)$.

---

**Completion of the Problem**

Let $(x,y,z)$ be any element in $S$. 
Then, either $x$ is a multiple of $3$, or it is not a multiple of $3$.

Suppose that $x$ is not a multiple of $3$. 
Then, by Lemma 1, $x^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}.$

So, by assumption, you have that :

- $x^2 - 3y^2 = 2z^2$
- $x^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}.$

This implies that $2z^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}.$ 
By Lemma 2, this implies that $z^2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}.$ 
By Lemma 1, **this is impossible**.

Therefore, for any element $(x,y,z) \in S$, the assumption that $x$ is not a multiple of $3$ has led to a contradiction.

Therefore, $x$ must be a multiple of $3$.

So, this implies that $(x^2 - 3y^2)$ is also a multiple of $3$.

Therefore, $2z^2$ must be a multiple of $(3)$.

Therefore. $z^2$ must be a multiple of $(3)$.

Therefore, $z$ must be a multiple of $(3)$.

---

So, it has been established that if $(x,y,z)$ is any element in $S$, that both $x$ and $z$ must be multiples of $3$.

By Lemma 3, this implies that both $x^2$ and $z^2$ are multiples of $9$.

Therefore, so is $2z^2$.

Also, you have that $x^2 - 3y^2 = 2z^2$.  
Therefore, $3y^2$ must be a multiple of $9$.

Therefore $y^2$ must be a multiple of $3$.

Therefore, $y$ must be a multiple of $3$.

---

So, it has been established that if $(x,y,z)$ is any element in $S$, that each of $x,y,z$ must be a multiple of $3$.

This implies that the ordered triplet $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{x}{3}, \frac{y}{3}, \frac{z}{3}\right)~$ is an ordered triplet of positive integers.  This begs the question: is this ordered triplet an element in $S$.

Since $(x,y,z)$ is an element in $S$, you know that

$$x^2 - 3y^2 = 2z^2.$$

This implies that

$$\frac{x^2}{9} - 3\left(\frac{y^2}{9}\right) = 2 \left(\frac{z^2}{9}\right).$$

This implies that

$$\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^2 - 3\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)^2 = 2 \left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^2.$$

This implies that
$~\displaystyle \left(\frac{x}{3}, \frac{y}{3}, \frac{z}{3}\right)~$
is a positive integer solution that is in $S$.

---

Therefore, you have that given any element $(x,y,z)$ in the set $S$, that the ordered triplet $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{x}{3}, \frac{y}{3}, \frac{z}{3}\right)~$ is also in the set $S$.

Consequently the assertion expressed in (2) above has been established.

Consequently, it has been established, that the equation in (1) above can not have any solution in positive integers.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I think I understand a little bit how to solve this.